# Adding a UIView as a subview to UIImageView

Tags: objective-c

I am working on creating a color picker for "iOS". I am using this project, since it does what i want: "[This](http://static.squarespace.com/static/52dd7a60e4b0e9abea4e2cad/52e28e46e4b0bd8a202b5c72/52e28f98e4b0bd8a202b7035/1390579608939/colorpicker1.zip?format=original)"

I want to create a moveable circle (`UIView`) on top of the palette (`UIImageView`).

What I want to do is, while users move the circle, take the touch point and call the method `getPixelColorAtLocation();` and change the background color of the circle to the color on current point. (Seen on most of the color palette/wheels)

The method `getPixelColorAtLocation()` is available on a child view. I created a circle with `UIView` on parent view, the problem is I cant call to `getPixelColorAtLocation()` from parent view.

My question is, Is there anyway to add a `UIView` as a `subView` to `UIImageView`. If I cant, what choices do I have to achieve what I want?

Comment: UIImageView is also a subclass of UIView. So, you can add new views to it.

Comment: I added [self addSubview:sampleView]; to viewDidLoad. But It doesn't display anything.

Comment: `UIImageView` doesn't have a `viewDidLoad`, so how you did that would be interesting.

Comment: I used initWithCoder and It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

```
[myImageView addSubview:sampleView];
```

Comment: Thanks. I added the code in initWithCoder, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

An image view is just a subclass of UIView, so you can add subviews to it however you'd like. If there's a reason why you can't do so, then you can always make it a subview of the image view's superview, move it to the front, and then use `convertPoint:toView:` to convert to the image view's coordinate system, then get the pixel color.